# Determining if the set of bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ is open and/or closed w.r.t. the product topology of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I would like some hints/pointers on how to proceed with the problem given my current thoughts:

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the set of sequences in $\mathbb{R}$, and $B \subset X$ the set of bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. Let the topology of $X$ be given by the product topology, i.e. the topology whose subbasis is the set $\{\mathrm{pr}_i^{-1}[U_i]\mid i \in \mathbb{N}, U_i \subset \mathbb{R}\}$ where each $U_i$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. When $X$ is equipped with a box topology, it is straightforward to show that $B$ is a clopen set. But I don't think that $B$ is an open set with the product topology of $X$, as with the product topology the basic elements are of the form $\prod_{i=1}^\infty S_i$ with only finitely many $S_i \neq \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, as the open sets of $X$ are given by the unions of these basic sets, it makes sense that the open sets of $X$ correspond to unbounded sequences $f$ with $|f(k)| \leq M, M \in \mathbb{R}$ for only finitely many indices.

Right now, I'm unsure whether the only way to finish the proof is by taking an arbitrary union of the basic sets and show that it does correspond to a union of products in which some terms are unbounded, as the union of Cartesian product seems to get out of hand quite quickly. That is, I'd really like to avoid working with an arbitrary union of Cartesian products (since the formula seems to expand exponentially in terms of the terms in the product), but I don't know any other approach.

As for closedness, since $X\setminus B$ corresponds to unbounded sequences, it follows from the reasoning above that for any $f \in X\setminus B$, there exists a neighborhood of unbounded sequences s.t. $f \in V \subset X\setminus B$. Hence $B$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Any mentioned base element in $X$ (in the product topology) contains both points in $B$ and points in $X\backslash B$. This can be seen by reformulating the condition on $S_i$ in a fixed base element $\prod_{n=1}^\infty S_i$ into the equivalent $\exists N\,\forall i\ge N: S_i=\mathbb R$.

From that it easily follows that neither $B$ nor $X\backslash B$ is open.